# Tear gases/chemical weapons for civillian use?

Tags: united-states, self-defense, is-x-legal

I was wondering if civilians can legally carry and use a chemical weapon/tear gas in an event where you need to protect yourself. I have found that pepper spray is okay for self defence in the USA, but all I can find on more potent substances is for police use or that they are banned in warfare.

An example is say someone needs to protect themself from an attacker and uses CS gas or benzyl chloride. How would this hold up on the victim's side in court?